# counting tokens and characters in list

Tags: python

say i have the following words i want to put in a list

```
"cat,dog,fish"         (first row)
"turtle,charzard,pikachu,lame"    (second row)
"232.34,23.4,242.12%"           (third row)
```

my question is how do i count the tokens in each line, like first row has 3, second row has 4, third one has 3. after that how do i count the chracters, then for each row decide which token has the most chracters? so that the output looks something like

```
token count = 3, character count = 10, fish has the most characters
token count = 4, character count = 25, charzard has the most characters
token count = 3, character count = 17, 242.12% has the most characters
```

only using simple list methods like len(). and using comma as a delimiter. thanks, im really lost because every time i try to strip the comma using strip(',') i get an error

Comment: I think you have to look at the `split` method

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Works for both `Python2` and `Python3`

```
rows = [ "cat,dog,fish", "turtle,charzard,pikachu,lame", "232.34,23.4,242.12%" ]
for row in rows:
    tokens = row.split(',')
    token_cnt = len(tokens)
    char_cnt = sum([len(token) for token in tokens])
    longest_token = max(tokens, key=len)
    print("token count = %d, character count = %d, %s has the most characters" %(token_cnt, char_cnt, longest_token))
```

Results:

```
>>> token count = 3, character count = 10, fish has the most characters
>>> token count = 4, character count = 25, charzard has the most characters
>>> token count = 3, character count = 17, 242.12% has the most characters
```

**EDITED:**

Now using `max` instead of my stupid choice of `sort` to find the longest word, inspired by @inspectorG4dget's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of strings:

```
def my_output(string_of_tokens):
    tokens = string_of_tokens.split(",")
    print "token count = %s, character count = %s, %s has the most characters" %
        (len(tokens), sum(map(len, tokens)), reduce(lambda a, b: a if len(a) > len(b) else b, tokens))

list = ["cat,dog,fish", "turtle,charzard,pikachu,lame", "232.34,23.4,242.12%"]
for l in list:
    my_output(l)
```

Comment: +1 for `reduce` :) in my answer i'm using `sort` to stupidly find the longest word.. however in `Python3` `reduce` was moved into `functools` which makes me too lazy to use it sometimes ><

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file of comma separated lines:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
  for i,line in enumerate(infile, 1):
    toks = line.split(',')
    print "row %d: token_count=%d character_count=%d '%s' has the most characters" %(len(toks), sum(len(t) for t in toks), max(toks, key=len))
```

Answer (score -2):

To count the number of tokens per line

Try this

```
import re
print len(re.findall(r'\w+', line))
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/v4l84Z)**